# change language format of QDateTimeEdit

Tags: qt, datepicker, datetime-format

When language format of windows is changed (control panel -> region and language), the language format of Qt components (ex: QDateTimeEdit) will change consequently. How can I fix language format of these components (ex: to be always English).

Comment: Why would you want to explicitly go against the user's request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it this way:

```
ui->dateTime->setLocale(QLocale::English);

ui->dateTime->calendarWidget()->setLocale(QLocale::English);
```